# Would it be opinion-based if I ask if a director's decision is ethical/acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I've read an article about a 1989 Iranian film where the male lead slaps the female lead very hard at one scene.

According to the article, the director didn't speak about the slap to the actress prior to filming that scene; so that her shock be real.

So if I ask "*Is it ethical and acceptable to not tell an actor/actress they're going to be slapped so that the reaction be real?*" will it be closed as opinion-based?

Comment: That seems very opinion-based. Ethical *by whose reckoning*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*Is it ethical?*" is mostly opinion-based. "*Does the practice conform to industry standards?*" is less opinion-based and is more likely to stay open.